# Cucumber is not generating index.html file in the target folder

Tags: eclipse, testing, cucumber

This is the code in my testRunner class:

```
package testRunners;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = {"src/test/resources"},
    glue = {"stepDef"},
    plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports"}
)

public class testRunner {

}
```

After running the code, the target folder does not show the index.html file (I have refreshed multiple times)

[image]

This is how it should look like:

[image]

How do I get an index.html report in the target folder?

Comment: What's inside the `cucumber-reports` file?

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje it's long; here's an excerpt of it on Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/AgFP9kSS

Comment: What does that look like to you?

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje code for generating a report? I don't know...

Comment: It's a html file. The `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<html lang="en">` should give that away. So try using `html:target/cucumber-reports/index.html` instead.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje I fixed the problem by using version 5.7.0 of cucumber-java and cucumber-junit instead of v. 6.9.1 that was giving me problems

Answer (score 1):

Use this
`plugin = {"html:target/cucumber-reports.html"}`

**.html** extension is required